# How to receive the digital data from an ASK/FSK Receiver (E.g. TDA 5210)

Tags: raspberry-pi, digital-communications, receiver

While reading the specs on a FSK/ASK Receiver (E.g. [TDA 5210](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-TDA5210-DS-v03_00-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d4625debb399015e286e612c3cb7) ) I am asking myself how actually the (non Manchester encoded) digital data look like and how to I receive it when sending from another device on the correct frequency

Can the DATA pin 25 "easily" be attached to a Raspberry Pi / Arduino?

Will this be a UART communication?

Comment: Read the sections on the data slicer.

Comment: Thank you, can you please  explain me this sentence a bit - `The output delivers a digital data signal (CMOS-like levels) for sbsequent circuits` and also for what CMOS-like stands for?

Comment: The output signal would be an uglier version of whatever the *unspecified* transmit modulation was.  In some cases that might be a UART type format, though it's perhaps not the best choice for less than perfect radio conditions.

Comment: And how would I connect and read it with a raspberry pi for instance?

Comment: You cannot until you figure out what the transmit coding is.  Since you have not provided any information about that, no one can help you.

Comment: I assume it is FSK modulated but there is no other encoding on top of it, like Manchester. So would it be possible to print out at least all incoming bits?

Comment: Without a coding it is **meaningless**.  Start from knowledge of whatever is *sending* the signal.  Otherwise you have a signal intelligence problem where you try to guess by looking at the pattern (and hope it isn't encrypted).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am asking myself how actually the (non Manchester encoded) digital
>   data look like and how to I receive it when sending from another
>   device on the correct frequency

The digital data should look the same as the transmitted data, in whatever format that is. However for the data slicer to work correctly the format should be something with approximately equal high and low times like [Manchester code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manchester_code).

> Can the DATA pin 25 "easily" be attached to a Raspberry Pi / Arduino?

Yes. Just make the sure the logic levels are compatible. The TDA 5210's data output high level is Vs-1V, ie. 4V on a 5V supply. For the Pi this should be reduced to 3.3V using a voltage divider.

> Will this be a UART communication?

[UART](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_asynchronous_receiver-transmitter) communication normally uses a serial format that does not attempt to even out the high and low times, so it is not generally recommended. It can work if you are careful to not send long periods of all 1's or 0's.

Note that radio links are inherently noisy. Whatever protocol you choose, it should be designed to reject noise by using preambles, sync sequences and checksums or CRC codes. This can be put on top of a UART signal, but may be more reliable if applied at the bit level. Since decoding the signal one bit at a time is quite CPU intensive, it is often done with a separate chip.

Comment: Thank you. Assuming the logic levels are compatible what tool/code can I use from the raspberry pi to output the data, once the pin is connected. And which gpio do you recommend?

Answer (score 1):

Since you may not be familiar with how Rx/Tx radios work, I suggest you search for App notes like I did.

TDA 5210  https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/TDA5200_AN_General_V1.3.pdf?fileId=db3a3043191a246301192d6e55392a5e

http://www.ck-electronic.dk/datasheets/app_notes/tda521x_ask_fsk_recievers_v1.1_app_note.pdf

https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-TDA7210-DS-v01_00-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d4625debb399015e2888ec453d3c

Most likely you will have to buy a card with a chip on it as the learning curve for RF is different than code 10101...